# Webview is getting reloaded when app goes into background Xamarin

Tags: webview, xamarin.android

Everytime when app goes background and comes foreground webview is getting reloaded. I just want to save the state in onpause and reload it when I resume the app.Could it be possible?

I am unable to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{     
   if (bundle == null) {  //everytime when I load, bundle is null and url is reloaded
   mapWebView.LoadUrl("url");
   } else {
     mapWebView.RestoreState(bundle);
   }
}

protected override void OnResume() {
        base.OnResume();
        if (mapWebView != null)
            mapWebView.OnResume();

    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        if (mapWebView != null)
        {
            mapWebView.OnPause();
            mapWebView.SaveEnabled = true;
            mapWebView.SaveState(bundle) //how to get bundle object here to save state

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*mapWebView.SaveState(bundle) //how to get bundle object here to save state*

**To get Bundle you need to override method**

```
public override void OnSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
    base.OnSaveInstanceState (outState, outPersistentState);
}
```

*Everytime when app goes background and comes foreground webview is getting reloaded. I just want to save the state in onpause and reload it when I resume the app.*

From your question it's hard to understand when you want to reload webview. Because onPause and OnResume will be called every time your app goes background/foreground.